# Icons on the website appear distorted upon initial entry to the site on Android

Tags: android, icons, mobile-website, distortion

Any Android device, using any browser, when I search for my website and enter the homepage, the icons appear distorted as shown in the image (There’s no issue when entering the site directly via the URL). Even after refreshing the site, the icons continue to appear distorted. However, when clicking on the website’s logo to refresh the homepage in this way, the icons become fine and don’t distort again.

Images:
[Photo that I take with two different phones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xcVb.jpg)

I didn’t try anything because didn’t find any solution.

Comment: Add code where you are setting attributes of your icon